# exclude multiple folder using gci

Tags: powershell

I have 2 subfolders 'PS Logs', 'Executables' in the root directory "C:\Temp\". How to exclude them using gci. I am doing the crude way where I exclude all the underlying files in these sub-folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -recurse -exclude *.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.FullName -match 'PS Logs') -and !($_.FullName -match 'Executables')} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there :)

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Recurse -Exclude "PS Logs", "Executables"
```

Comment: Can you provide more info. Is there any errors, what is the OS and PS version, what privilege you have. I done test before I post it with same folder names on my Win 10 machine (PS 5.1) and it works, Now test it on my work PC with PS 5.0 and it not.

Comment: But in PowerShell always can use another approach, and here it is another oneliner:
`Get-ChildItems C:\temp -Recurse | Where {($_.FullName -notlike "C:\Temp\PS Logs\*") -and {($_.FullName -notlike "C:\Temp\Executables\*")} `

Comment: Windows 2012 server ps v3.5

Comment: If you did not upgrade anything .NET should be 3.5, and PS 3.0 on Windows Server 2012. 
Code line from my pervious comment should work correct.